# Its return type 'void | Element' is not a valid JSX element. Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Element | null'

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-testing-library

I am getting this Type Error in one of my component in which i want to redirect  users on load
based on  conditions
ex- If user is not login redirect him to login page

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router';
const someCompo = () => {
     const history = useHistory();
     if(!user) return history.push('/login');
     return(<div>...component </div>)
}
export default someCompo;
```

but when i test this component in render of react-testing library. i am getting this type error

In .test File

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import someCompo from '../someCompo ';
it('Check Redirect', () => {
   render(<someCompo />)
}
```

But when I use Redirect it doesn't show error

```
  if (!user) return <Redirect to='/login'/>
```

Can someone please explain why it's giving me a error

Comment: A React component must always return a JSX Element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant return `void` as an element. and if you want to do something like this it would be better to use the `useEffect`

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router';
const someCompo = ({ user }) => {
   const history = useHistory();
   useEffect(() => {
     if(!user) {
       history.push('/login');
     }
   }, [user]);
   if(!user) return null;
   return <div>...component </div>;
}
export default someCompo;
```

`return history.push('/login')` will return `void`, as `history.push('/login')` will return `void`. and `void` is not a valid react element.

the ugly way without useEffect hook would be:

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router';
const someCompo = ({ user }) => {
   const history = useHistory();
   if(!user) {
     history.push('/login');
     return null;
   }
   return <div>...component </div>;
}
export default someCompo;
```